# Matplotlib ugly graph on xubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

i have a strange problem.
I have a python script in which i plot some data with plt.errorbar(...) and plt.plot(...).
The strange fact is, depending on the OS i am using, the graph looks different.
With elementary OS everything is ok, but with xubuntu it looks like this! (picture allegated).
The script is EXACTLY the same.
How can i solve to have it like elementary os one? (It's the one with tiny bars and without "flat" theme like).
(the picture are different only in titles, but every other thing is exactly the same).
[image: ugly]

[image: good (elementary os)]

Comment: This is probably an issue with your matplotlib.rc files on the different OSes. If you don't modify them manually, it can be caused by a difference in the versions of matplotlib.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
How can i have then the elementary os one?

Comment: You may need to check a backend that works on all your desired OS and looks like you want. Check this: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Comment: Compare the configs and set up both to look the same. I can't really tell you without having more information.

Comment: That too. You may have different default graphical packages installed which would then provide different backends as @JosepValls says. For example, the `qt4agg` backend will look very different from say `tkagg`.

Comment: Ok, i tried changing backend but no one except tkagg (which is the default one) seems to work; they dont display and save figures, instead of the use of plt.show() and plt.savefig("....pdf").
Why that?

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious reason the two plots look different, is that you use different versions of matplotlib on the two systems.

Once you use the same version, you should make sure that the matplotlib [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) are the same.

The backend in use should only have a minor influence on the appearance (e.g. line thickness might be slightly different in saved figures or so).